# Enabled SSL on Xampp, but now cannot access mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, ssl

I've successfully setup xampp to serve my virtualhost project via SSL on the usual port 443. But now I get an error saying: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I realise using root isn't ideal, but it's only a local project. If I access the project without SSL it all works fine.

What is the easiest way to solve this? Do I need to communicate with mysql through SSL even though it's all on the same machine? And if so can someone point me at a good tutorial to do this?

Not sure if this is relevant but this is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost test_site:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test_site/public"
    ServerName test_site
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/test_site/public">
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

The SSL cert was created through makecert.bat in Xampp.

Comment: SSL on 443 is usually for http, not mySQL? What did you set up to serve SSL, Apache or mySQL?

Comment: What is actually accessing the database server? Is it apache itself, so maybe the authentication step? Or some scripting language?

Comment: And please post the _full_ error message and everything from the http servers error log file. You need to provide details!

Comment: I'm using Xampp, so its an Apache, Mysql and PHP stack sitting on windows. I didn't think SSL would affect apaches ability to access mysql. But it seems to have, as I said it still works fine when I don't access the site through SSL.
I'm accessing mysql through PDO in PHP

This is the actual error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)